# Wrapping parameters returned from Factory Bot in another parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I am requiring a particular parameter using params.require(:business) in rails but I am having issues getting Factory Bot to build the parameters correctly.

I've read the factory bot docs but don't see anything that would solve this issue. Googling it didn't really provide a lot. I may be asking the question using incorrect vocab. I am new to rails and things might be called something different than what I am searching for but my code should explain my issue.

Factory:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :business do
    description { Faker::Company.industry }
    name { Faker::Company.name }
    sequence(:email) { |n| "business#{n}@example.com" }
  end
end
```

Factory output:

```
{:description=>"Restaurants", :name=>"Wuckert LLC", :email=>"business3@example.com"}
```

It provides the correct parameters and tests pass until I add the following to the controller:

```
params.require(:business)
```

I am expecting something like this would solve the issue:

```
{:business => { :description=>"Restaurants", :name=>"Wuckert LLC", :email=>"business3@example.com"}}
```

If there is something that isn't good practice that would prevent this from even being an issue I am open to suggestions.

Comment: You know you can do `{ business: FactoryBot.create(:business) }`?

Comment: I tried that. It doesn't work. I will continue looking for a solution and update the question once I find one.

Comment: _Doesn't work_ doesn't give much information in order to give an answer. Add some error logs if any.